# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

Python is version 3.7.6, Django is version 3.0.8, I am trying to deploy from aws,
but adding container_commands gives an error
container_commands and DATABASES code

```
 - container_commands:   01_migrate:
       command: "django-admin.py migrate"
       leader_only: true   02_compilemessages:
       command: "django-admin.py compilemessages"
   
   option_settings:   aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
       WSGIPath: config.wsgi:application   aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
       DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: config.settings


 - DATABASES = {
           "default": {
               "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
               "HOST": os.environ.get("RDS_HOST"),
               "NAME": os.environ.get("RDS_NAME"),
               "USER": os.environ.get("RDS_USER"),
               "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("RDS_PASSWORD"),
               "PORT": "5432",
           }
       }
```

The problem seems to be caused by django-admin.py migrate
Enter django-admin.py migrate command

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
   DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define
   the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
   settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I get this message, I don't know how to fix it,

my github : https://github.com/dopza86/air_bnb_clone

I need help,thankyou

Comment: Where did you setup `DATABASES` and the other values. This does not seem to be `.ebextentions`?

Comment: Try running manage.py instead of django-admin.py. The manage.py script will configure Django settings and set a default value for DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Comment: DATABASES is set in settings.py and the contents of django.config file in .ebextentions